# Filtering rows by specific values %in% ONE OR MORE specified columns

Tags: r

I have a large number of data frame columns beginning with "country" and suffixed numerically by 1 (e.g., `country1`, `country2`, `country3`). I want to use `dplyr` to `filter` my dataframe `df` to rows where **ONE OR MORE** of the variables include certain country names as values (i.e., `country1 OR country2 OR country3 %in% "Brazil`"), along with a number of other conditions.

I've tried using `grep` to do this, but the problem I encounter is that the function is evaluated at the same time as the rest of the `filter` function, so I get an error message. Here's what I've tried:

```
df1 <- filter(df, 
                a %in% value1
              & b %in% value2
              & grep("^country.*", colnames(df), value = TRUE) %in% c("Brazil")
```

Of course, R just evaluates the `grep` function as ...

```
& c("country1", "country2", "country3", ... ) %in% c("Brazil")
```

And returns a logical vector, where obviously none of the values == "Brazil":

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
```

Is there a way to do this without laboriously typing all variables? For example...

`& (country1 %in% "Brazil" | country2 %in% "Brazil" | country3` ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try something like this. I start by creating an index of the rows where "Brazil" is present in any of the "country" columns and then use the index to subset/filter the data:

```
indx <- df %>% select(starts_with("country")) %>% 
             mutate_each(funs(grepl("Brazil", .))) %>% 
             rowSums > 0
indx
#[1]  TRUE FALSE

df %>% filter(indx)
#  country1 country2 country3
#1        A        B   Brazil
```

#### Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(country1 = "A", country2 = "B", country3 = c("Brazil", "C"))
df
#  country1 country2 country3
#1        A        B   Brazil
#2        A        B        C
```

#### Edit

If you want to look for multiple country names, you only need a slight modification to paste the country names of interest together, e.g. like this:

First, I'll slightly modify the sample data to include a third row with "Argentina".

```
df <- data.frame(country1 = "A", country2 = "B", country3 = c("Brazil", "C", "Argentina"))
df
#  country1 country2  country3
#1        A        B    Brazil
#2        A        B         C
#3        A        B Argentina
```

Then you can store the country names you  want to look for in a vector:

```
x  <- c("Brazil", "Argentina", "USA")
```

Now, build the indx again, but paste the country names of "x" together so that `grepl` will look for any of them (trick is to collapse with "|" - logical OR):

```
indx <- df %>% select(starts_with("country")) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(grepl(paste(x, collapse = "|"), .))) %>% 
  rowSums > 0
```

Now you can subset your data either the standard way or for example using dplyr:

```
df[indx,]
#  country1 country2  country3
#1        A        B    Brazil
#3        A        B Argentina
df %>% filter(indx)
#  country1 country2  country3
#1        A        B    Brazil
#2        A        B Argentina
```

Comment: Building filtering indices is a very powerful strategy ... even in regular R.

Comment: @beginneR This is a fantastic solution, and almost exactly what I was looking for! However, since I'm always looking to generalize my functions, I'm wondering if there is another function like `grep` that would accommodate character vectors longer than length 1 for the `pattern` argument. For instance, I might be interested in not just searching for "Brazil", but "Brazil" and "Argentina". Thanks.

Comment: @Nicapyke, I updated my answer to look for multiple country names.

Comment: @beginneR Awesome, thanks again! Was never aware of the `collapse` argument in `paste`.

Comment: @beginneR One question about your use of "." as an argument for `grepl`. Why does that work? What does it stand for? Seems like it might be a pipe or something for the columns selected in the last `%>%` call.

Comment: That is used in `mutate_each` and `summarise_each` to refer to the columns that are passed to the functions, here, "." represents the columns country1, country2, country3. Look at the help file `?mutate_each` for more examples.

Answer (score 6):

More compact version:

```
df %>% filter(str_detect(country1:country3, "Brazil"))
#  country1 country2 country3
#         1        A        B   Brazil
```

(requires `stringr` as well as `dplyr`)

This may also work, per @beginneR's comment:

```
df %>% filter(str_detect(starts_with("country"), "Brazil"))
```

Comment: +1 for a nice and "clean" answer. One thing I thought of: what if the country columns are not next to each other (hypothetically) - I think in that case there would be some additional tweak (perhaps with `grep`) necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a vectorized solution using base R

```
dat[rowSums(dat[grepl("^country\\d+$", names(dat))] == "Brazil") > 0, ]
##   Random1 Random2 country1 country2 country3
## 1       C       D        A        B   Brazil
```

---

Or `data.table`s binary search (which will be a certain winner for a big data set)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, indx := rowSums(.SD[, grepl("^country\\d+$", names(dat)), with = F] == "Brazil") > 0]
setkey(dat, indx)[J(TRUE)]
##    Random1 Random2 country1 country2 country3 indx
## 1:       C       D        A        B   Brazil TRUE
```

---

**Data set**

```
dat <- data.frame(Random1 = c("C", "Brazil"), Random2 = "D", 
                  country1 = "A", country2 = "B", country3 = c("Brazil", "C"))
#   Random1 Random2 country1 country2 country3
# 1       C       D        A        B   Brazil
# 2  Brazil       D        A        B        C
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution as well. I need to build more familiarity with the `data.table` package, beyond just using `fread` in place of `read.csv` for large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a logical matrix as a helper and take the unique rows

```
dat[sort(unique(row(dat)[dat == "Brazil"])),]
#   country1 country2  country3 country4  country5
# 3   Brazil   Brazil Argentina   Brazil    Brazil
# 4   Mexico    Chile    Brazil    Chile Argentina
# 5   Brazil    Chile Argentina   Brazil Argentina
# 6   Mexico    Chile Argentina   Brazil    Brazil
```

Altrnatively, you can use `which`

```
w <- which(dat == "Brazil", arr.ind=TRUE)[,"row"]
dat[sort(unique(w)),]
```

Where the `dat` data is:

```
set.seed(25)
country <- c("Brazil", "Chile", "Argentina", "Mexico")
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(country, 30, TRUE), 6))
dat <- setNames(dat, paste0("country", 1:ncol(dat)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the columns together to get a super column and then grep it for Brazil?

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(rep('Canada',10), 'Brazil'), 20, replace=T),
                         ncol=5),
                  stringsAsFactors=F)

> dat
      X1     X2     X3     X4     X5
1 Canada Canada Canada Canada Canada
2 Canada Canada Canada Canada Brazil
3 Canada Brazil Canada Canada Canada
4 Canada Canada Canada Canada Canada
```

Then:

```
dat$X6 <- apply(dat, 1, paste, collapse="")
grepl('Brazil', dat$X6)

> grepl('Brazil', dat$X6)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

As expected, returns TRUE only for rows with Brazil in them (i.e. 2 and 3)

Comment: The `paste`ing might take a while if the data is large.  I thought of this too, it's a great idea if efficient.

Comment: Yes, you could do something like `df %>% unite(countries, country1:country3, sep = ", ") %>% filter(str_detect(countries, "Brazil"))`